# double Tap a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uialertview

I try to open an `UIAlertView` with two `textfield` with the text from the cell which I selected. I use this code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(edit:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    [tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapRecognizer];


    CardTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"editCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellFirstText = cell.cellFirstText.text;
    NSString *cellSecondText = cell.cellSecondText.text;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cellFirstText forKey:@"cellFirstToEdit"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cellSecondText forKey:@"cellSecondToEdit"];
}

-(void)edit: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"save", nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;

    [[alert textFieldAtIndex:1] setSecureTextEntry:NO];

    [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"cellFirstToEdit"];
    [alert textFieldAtIndex:1].text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"cellSecondToEdit"];

    alert.tag = 3;

    [alert show];
}
```

But the problem is, even I click (ones) on the row, the text changed to the default text. I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is wrong cause you are creating a UITapGestureRecognizer every time the user taps on a cell, not when the cell loads, and also you're assigning it to the view, not to the cell.

So try this:

Move this code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(edit:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

[tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapRecognizer];
```

To the cellForRowAtIndexPath method after you initialize the cell, and change the `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];` to a `[cell addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];` cause you want to add the gesture to the cell not to the view.

I don't know if that will really solve your problem, but are two things that I think are wrong in your code. In theory it should work.

EDIT:

Also try setting the message on the alert initialization to `nil`. Also, is it really necessary to use NSUserDefaults to store those variables? Can't they be stored just in two NSString properties, or are you persisting those variables for some reason?

Comment: Thanks, it works. I moved it to the cellForRowAtIndexPath and changed it to [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];